# In "The 100", has the issue of the Alpha Station Ring at Arkadia/Camp Jaha tipping over ever been addressed?

Tags: the-100

I'm watching Season 3 of The 100, and looking at Arkadia, the settlement previously known as Camp Jaha, which the survivors have settled beneath:

[image]

it seems to me that no one is worried about the structural integrity of this space station which fell to the ground from space. It seems like there would be an imminent risk of the Ring Section tipping over and killing hundreds of survivors below.

Has this been addressed in the series so far?

Comment: Logically speaking, that's one of the first things they would have check once they, umm, landed, and Camp Jaha was set up.

Comment: also, based on the shape, I had assumed roughly 1/2 of the ship was embedded in the ground, keeping it upright.

Answer (score 1):

So this actually becomes an issue in season 4. If you haven't watched season 4 yet, don't read this!

> In order to survive another nuclear fallout, the Arkadian citizens decide to prepare the "Ring Section" so that they can hide in it. Of course, the show writers could not let it be that easy, so in comes a grounder who ends up blowing up the entire ship.

So to answer your question, the ring is actually very stable, even when it was blown up, the "base" of the ring did not "tip over". The ring collapsed, obviously, because of the explosion, but the bottom of the visible portion of the ring was secured and rooted very deep. The ring would not have fallen over under normal conditions.

Comment: please use the spoiler tag to properly format your "spoilers" in the future, I will do it for you so you can see how it is done but that is the preferred method of alerting the reader as often once a person starts reading, it might be too late already. Good luck and welcome. Refer: https://movies.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers